# Is the Hadoop scalability linear or proportional to number of nodes?

Tags: hadoop

Is common to see this sentence: "Hadoop Scales Linearly". But, is there any performance evaluation to confirm this?

In my evaluations, Hadoop processing capacity scales linearly, but not proportional to number of nodes, the processing capacity achieved with 20 nodes is not the double of the processing capacity achieved with 10 nodes. Is there any evaluation about this?

Thank you!

Comment: I would think it would depend on what you're measuring. There's likely times that adding more disks to the nodes you have helps more than adding new nodes.

Comment: Evaluating storage capacity I think this behavior is expected. If I add more disk, i get more space but is not need more replication. But, my concern is about processing capacity. Thank you, Ilion.

Comment: These jobs are often IO bound, not CPU bound. Adding more disks and modifying the data.dir settings allow each note to write more concurrently, thus you can process faster and more concurrently. It's not just about space.